# Как отправить POST запрос на веб-приложение?

Tags: android, html

Доброго времени суток и заранее извиняюсь, если неправильно формулирую мысль!

Вся суть: У меня есть веб-приложение на котором имеется страница (допустим 127.0.0.1:5000/hello), содержание которой две строки Name и Sex и кнопка Submit для подтверждения.
Мне нужно с Android приложения на котором есть такие-же две строки и кнопка, передать их на ту страницу (mysite.ru/hello).
Хеуп! Впервые пытаюсь разобрать такое задание. Примеров с пояснениями в ваших интернетах мало..
Прошу, не кидайтесь огурцами! За любую помощь/ресурс, буду очень сильно признателен!

Comment: Используйте [retrofit](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/retrofit.php). В ссылке слегка устаревшая (но все еще рабочая) статья на эту тему. Язык русский. На английском информация свежее и в бОльшем объеме. Этот наш интернет до краев забит примерами и объяснениями, просто для их понимания нужен хоть какой-то минимальный уровень

Comment: на чём у вас сайт реализован?

Comment: FLASK, Python 3.8